# Android - Add new buttons in listview dynamically

Tags: android, button

I've a Listview with two linear layouts and there is one button add new row . When i click add new row button i want to create new row of buttons dynamically. After that click on that created button i want to show an time picker dialog . When user click set time button i want to set that time in that button. My problem is All the buttons(with different id) are added fine and when click that button time picker dialog was pop up. But after click set time button the time will not set . How can i add this time to the button. How can i handle this button ?

It is my piece of code inside of listview onscroll listener

```
final LinearLayout l1 = LinearLayout) List_Layout.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout l12 = (LinearLayout) List_Layout.getChildAt(1);    
final Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
final Button button1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());

add_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        button.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        button1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        button.setId(0);
        button1.setId(1);
        l1.addView(button, lparams);
        l12.addView(button1, lparams);
    }
}
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
    }
}
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("tag 1", button1.getTag()+"");
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
    }
});
```

Rest of the codes for timepicker dialog is works fine

It's just sample code

Please anyone help me get out from this riddle.

[image]

Edit:

```
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 998;
private int hour;
    private int minute;
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
case TIME_DIALOG_ID:

            return new TimePickerDialog(this, 
                    timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);
}
return null;
}
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                int selectedMinute) {
hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;
}
}
```

Comment: where is the code to set the time ?

Comment: I've added code for time see my edit.

Comment: Save the clicked button in a variable. Once time is set set the text for the button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set text of `button` or `button1` to the time that was actually picked by the user. To do so, code some `button.setText(<formatted time>)` in the `timePickerListener`.

Here's some line of code, I use to format date and time from a `java.util.Date` object:

```
Date date = new Date();
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(context);
java.text.DateFormat timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
button.setText(String.format("%s %s", dateFormat.format(date), timeFormat.format(date)));
```

In your case of the time picker you can just format the selected values into a string:

```
button.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", selectedHour, selectedMinute));
```

Comment: button.settext("") will work i know . How can i handle that dynamically created button inside of TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener method

Comment: All you need is a handle to `button`. Define it as `private` to the Activity class and you're able to reference it.